# Color Fluctuation when moving vector data over raster background in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.3, vector, editing

My ArcMap view has a raster background. When moving vector polygons, there is a colour fluctuation inside the polygon. If I change the polygon's symbology to hollow, the effect disappears and there is no color fluctuation.

Is there any way to move the polygons without the color fluctuation, without changing the symbology to hollow?

[image: Color Fluctuation in ArcMap]

Comment: @BERA I'm 99% sure it's the Edit tool, this is just the way ArcMap works. I reworded it to make the problem clearer, I'm pretty sure the raster type is irrelevant here.